# How would you create a hard link (Linux) from within an application without passing arguments to the ln utility directly?

Tags: c#, linux

For the sake of example, I'll be using C#. I need to know what piece of the api to call.

I've been unsuccessful in general searches for this as it seems most people prefer to simply call the ln utility up and pass it the appropriate arguments. I've been told its not good form to call a shell utility for anything you can reasonably do otherwise.

I know .net and mono do not contain any way of handling symlinks or hard links. I have been pointed to system.io, but I was unsuccessful in finding documentation for hard linking there.

For those wondering what a hard link is,

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link

Comment: call [`link` or `linkat`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/link.html). I don't know how you would do that from c# ([this](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/) may help though). BTW add the language tag to the question.

Comment: If I have to I'll switch to an appropriate language, but Thank You I've got some reading to do.

Comment: @Diego I think your comment could be an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assuming you mean, how do I create a hard link without shelling out the the ln command.

Short answer,

```
using Mono.Unix.Native;
Mono.Unix.Native.Syscall.link(string oldname, string newname).
```

---

Ultimately you do this by invoking the link() function

Looking at the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/link.2.html): link() creates a new link (also known as a hard link) to an existing file. The linkat() function is also documented which might be a better choice for you.

> int link(const char *oldpath, const char *newpath);

Clearly, not a C# friendly system call (they rarely are). So, as far as calling it from C# is concerned, you can either go through creating the necessary steps to call it from C# (translating the .h constants, etc.) -- or you can just call link() directly from a C/C++ interface module in your project, and then call that interface from your C# code. Since Unix system calls are not C++ based, you don't run into name mangling problems.

To call external functions, you use pinvoke technology (also included in Microsofts .Net framework). A bit long too replicate everything in that reference, but the key features are pretty simple.

Link to the shared library using DllImport, and declare the external functions you need. E.g.

```
[DllImport ("libc.so")]
public static int link(string oldpath, string newpath)
```

You might also find an os interface module written in C# that translates system call errors into more natural C# exceptions is a better choice in the long term. To be honest, linking the .so file and invoking the Linux system calls is not that hard and you might conclude you prefer this approach over a separate C/C++ module.

If you ever have to migrate your mono code to a windows platform, using an os interface module will simplify your life. BTW, you can also create hard links on Windows on NTFS file systems, but few Windows people use them, much less expect them.

**And finally, the real answer**: The [Mono.Unix NameSpace](http://mapsbkp.geolives.com/monodoc/index.aspx?link=T%3AMono.Unix.Native.Stdlib) is a nice choice for most system calls, and link() is not an exception. If you look in the SysCall class of Mono.Unix.Native you should find the link() method.

```
using Mono.Unix.Native;
SysCall.Link(ExistingName, NewLinkName);
```

Unfortunately, the Mono docs do not use a RESTful interface, so I can't give you are direct link the correct page. [Start at](http://mapsbkp.geolives.com/monodoc/index.aspx?link=T%3AMono.Unix.Native.Stdlib) and then drill down using the tree interface

I thought a teach you to fish answer was more appropriate in this case. You could download the mono native source and see exactly how mono does it.

Noticed the comment by Diego - His comment answer was include within my longer answer.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend doing this in a weird way, and that is I would just use `ln` for it... yes I wouldn't bother looking about a C# native implementation, or searching through a bunch of functions of other languages, but instead I would be doing:

```
var command = "ln source dest"; 

var proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process ();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "/bin/bash";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "-c \"" + command + "\"";
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
proc.Start ();

while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream) {
    string line = proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine ();

    // In case you need output do stuff in here
}
```

I usually do that for the most things I need to do on Linux since there are a lot of things I know how to do with bash it makes a lot of sense to abuse the info from within C#. Whats more you  could turn the above into a method "CallBash" and just pass the command you want to execute.